# The image is changed only once at @click event with vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, carousel

I'm using VueJS for this project, I'm having trouble changing the source of the img at the click of a button.

I have the img files in a local folder. Now they have a different id, so I should be able to change the id at every @click iteration.

**This is the HTML code:**

```
<div id="app">

    <div class="container" >
        <div class="slider-wrapper" tabindex="0">

            <div class="item">
                <img :src='allSlides[currentIndex].image' alt="Svezia" />
                <div class="text">
                    <h3>{{allSlides[currentIndex].title}}</h3>
                    <p>
                        {{allSlides[currentIndex].text}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="thumbs">
                <div class="prev" @click="prev"></div>
                <div class="next" @click="next"></div>
                <div v-for="slide in allSlides" class="thumb">
                    <img :src="slide.image" :alt="slide.title"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

**This is the javascript code:**

```
const slides = [
{
    image: 'img/01.jpg',
    title: 'Sweden',
    text: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et temporibus voluptatum suscipit tempore aliquid deleniti aut veniam inventore eligendi ex ad ullam, cumque provident totam omnis, magnam dolores dolorum corporis.',
},
{
    image: 'img/02.jpg',
    title: 'Switzerland',
    text: 'Lorem ipsum.',
},
{
    image: 'img/03.jpg',
    title: 'Britain',
    text: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
},
{
    image: 'img/04.jpg',
    title: 'Germany',
    text: 'Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et temporibus voluptatum suscipit tempore aliquid deleniti aut veniam inventore eligendi ex ad ullam.',
},
{
    image: 'img/05.jpg',
    title: 'Paradise',
    text: 'Et temporibus voluptatum suscipit tempore aliquid deleniti aut veniam inventore eligendi ex ad ullam, cumque provident totam omnis.',
}

new Vue ({
el: "#app",
data: {
    allSlides: slides,
    state: "active",
    currentIndex: 0

},

methods: {
    prev() {
        this.allSlides[this.currentIndex].image;
        this.currentIndex++;

        if(this.currentIndex == this.allSlides.length){
            this.currentIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, my final result should be a carousel that slides through the different locations, changing the image and information at every button interaction.
Thank you all.

**IMPORTANT, I HAVE TO USE VUE.JS 2**

Comment: where is your `next` function

Comment: I'm waiting to develop the `next` function, I would like to let the `prev` function work before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code that you wrote, `this` is **not defined**; Based on the current syntax, you should define a variable and assign your Vue instance to it, and use that variable instead of `this`. Here is the code:

```js
cosnt vm = new Vue ({
el: "#app",
data: {
    current_slide: slides,
    all_slides: slides,
    state: "active",
    currentImg: 'img/01.jpg',
    newImgId: 1

},

methods: {
    prev() {
        
        if (vm.newImgId < 5) {
            vm.newImgId = vm.newImgId + 1
        } else {
            vm.newImgId = 1
        };
        vm.currentImg = `img/0${vm.newImgId}.jpg`;
        
    },
}
```

Also, **note that** since you are mentioning the `next` method in your HTML, you should define it, or at least comment it out, otherwise you would get an error.

Here is the [related link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I've used your approach. 
The problem is that at the click the image change only one time, it should change more times to slide between the images. 
It's like after one @click iteration the button is stuck.

Comment: `[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

(found in <Root>)`

Comment: This is the error that I see in the console.

Comment: can you share your html code as well? where are you using prev() as an event handler? @Alessio

Comment: also, you should use a computed property for `currentImg` since its value is calculated based on the value of `newImgId `

Comment: I've edited the code, so I posted the question again with all the edits I've done.
@mo3n

Comment: since you are mentioning the `next` method in your HTML, you should define it, or at least comment it out, otherwise you would get an error  @Alessio

Comment: @Alessio so how about accepting my answer? :))

Comment: @Alessio you do not have to fully develop `next` method, but at least you should define it as an empty function